# How to use Access Modifiers in Java (why use getter methods?)

Tags: java

I have simple but stupid question. We use access modifiers in Java to access variables in a Class. I do not understand that if we can access a private class variable outside the class using properties defined in public class, then what is difference between public and private? It is still accessible outside private class. I do not understand the concept of this public private concept.

Comment: Question not clear enough. May you give a short source code example ?

Comment: why don't you read documentation or a java book? if you get some answers here, they won't be different than what is written in the books.

Comment: Is this private class an inner class?

Comment: @YvesMartin source code? what are you trying to say? he even didn't read the concepts, this question has nothing to do with source code. are you joking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking why someone would write this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int value;
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public int setValue(int val) {
        value = val;
    }
}
```

instead of simply:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int value;
}
```

The main reason is to hide the internal structure of `MyClass` from client code. The benefit is that this allows you to more easily modify the internal structure of `MyClass`. Perhaps, for instance, you decide that another field in `MyClass` needs to be updated whenever `value` changes. This would be very difficult to implement without error if accesses to `value` were scattered everywhere in your code (and nigh-on impossible if your code served as a library for someone else's code).

Additional benefits are that you can, if necessary, rewrite `getValue()` and `setValue(int)` to synchronize access to the value, to log writes to `value`, or do any number of other things.

Answer (score 1):

private members and functions can only be accessed from within the class (there are other techniques such as reflection to access them from outside the class, but let's ignore those for now).

a public function or member can be accessed from any other class. a public function can access private members from its own class

In general, public functions are things you want to expose to outside classes. They usually define what the class does and not how it does it. For example, if class A has a public function called doSomething, class B can call that function. It doesn't care how A does it, it just cares that it does it. Internally, doSomething might access some internal private variables. Because B is not dependent on those variables, those details can change without affecting the method call.

This concept is known as `encapsulation` or `information hiding`. Some googling on these terms should provide more detailed examples.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are asking what is the difference between:

```
public class A {
    public int x;
}
```

and

```
public class A {
    private int x;

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
}
```

The difference is that in the first case you are accessing the class member as-is, without additional logic. In the second case you may have additional logic since you are calling a method. For example:

```
public class A {
    private int x;

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public void setX(int x) { if(x > 0) this.x = x; }
}
```

In this case you are only setting a new value for `x` if the value provided is greater than 0.

This concept is called **encapsulation**. It allows you to transparently handle various special conditions without exposing the logic outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

It's called [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). You can think of it as controlling the internal state of your object and only presenting a public interface or contract that is appropriate for the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables (or fields) are declared private for a number of reasons (all based on a concept called [information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)).

One reason is that you may wish to control access to your field (eg. filtering certain values).

eg.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    // construtor and getter

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the name of a person may not be null");
        }
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

A second reason is that we may wish to hide the specific implementation of a class we are using. The interface `List` specifies a contract for accessing an ordered collections of elements. `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are two different implementations of `List`. Internally, you may use `ArrayList` as your implementation, but only wish to expose publicly that you using list. This means that if you subsequently find that a `LinkedList` would be a better implemenation then you won't break any that relies on your class.

Consider class B.

```
public class B {

    private ArrayList<String> list;

    // constructor

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListTheBadWay() {
        return list;
    }

}
```

I could easily use class B like this.

```
B b = new B();
List<String> list1 = b.getList();
ArrayList<String> list2 = b.getListTheBadWay();
```

If the class B was changed to use LinkedList then the line that used `getListTheBadWay()` would break, whereas the line that used `getList()` would continue to work.